# Javascript http status code

Tags: jquery, xmlhttprequest, auth

Как можно реализовать проверку на 401 и 403 код без окошка авторизации.
**UPD**
забыл добавить то что запрос на другой домен.

Answer (score 1):

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/non-existent/page/',
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
        console.log(jqXHR.status); // 404
    }
});
```

**UPD** Изменяем на следующее:

```
$(document).ajaxError(function(event, request, settings) {
    console.log(request.status);
});
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/non-existent/page/',
});
```

Comment: не подойдет, так вылезет окно авторизации basi auth.

Comment: Дополнил в ответе

Comment: хм, уже что-то только откидывает 404.